# Where to find sample UDDI entries

Tags: web-services, registry, uddi

I'm doing a research in semantic web services. For that I need some sample UDDI entries or a registry with entries that has more then 100 services. Can somebody point me to find them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your own registry, check out Apache jUDDI.

The latest source code has a UDDI "migration" tool that will let you export data from other registries and import it into your own. In addition, there's an example that will let you load up a registry with some fictitious data.

There's also these sites, although they are not specifically UDDI based.
http://www.service-repository.com/
http://webservices.washington.edu/service/browse/

Just google "web service registry" if you need seed data